# Why won't this work? (Sprite-Kit related)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on an iOS game and I want the clowns to spawn outside of the scene, then make their way down. What I had in mind was to create them all, and place them 360 pixels apart on the non-visible scene.

Like this:

```
SKSpriteNode *clown = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"clown.png"] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];

RandomPosition = arc4random() %248;
RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 34;
clown.position = CGPointMake (RandomPosition, self.frame.size.height + 360);
clown.zPosition = 1.0;
clown.name = @"clown";
[self addChild:clown .png];
```

Note the first clown is placed 360px above the top of the scene. I wanted to do this for 9 clowns, so the second one would be 720px above the scene, 3rd 1080px, etc... But before I even got to that I noticed that this one wasn't even working. If I set the 360 to 40 it works, but no value higher than that? Why is this. How can I fix this code to work? Is there a more efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Perhaps theres a way to do it with an array?

Heres the scrolling method incase anyone needs it:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"clown" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    SKSpriteNode *mercury = (SKSpriteNode *)node;
    CGPoint debVelocity = CGPointMake(0, -DEB_VELOCITY);
    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(debVelocity,_dt);
    clown.position = CGPointAdd(amtToMove, clown.position);

    if (clown.position.y > self.frame.size.height + 40) {
        [clown removeFromParent];
    }

}];
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want the clown above the scene you be subtracting 360, not adding.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work either :( @rdelmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, these lines would seem to be a problem for clowns more than 40 pixels above the frame.

```
if (clown.position.y > self.frame.size.height + 40) {
    [clown removeFromParent];
```

Comment: Wow hahaha, i feel so dumb. Thanks so much, hahaha